# 'Cannot resolve symbol' (design + v7 + annotation)

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

A friend of mine sent me some activity from his app. I created a new activity for each one and copy-paste the code in the new empty activity. Now I got some problem with the imports:

```
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
    import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

And here there is my Gradle - app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.progand"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
    }

    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
    }
```

I tried adding all the depedences that i found online and nothing solved the problem, it still gives me the error "cannot resolve symbol 'design/v7/annotation' " and I can't run my app to test the activities.
I really dunno what I'm doing wrong, sorry if it seems naive but it's my first time trying android studio 3.4.2, SDK Version 29.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix `com.android.support` and `androidx` artifact. You should be using all the dependencies of `androidx` only.
Replace 
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` with `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'.`

Remove `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'` since you already have androidx dependency of `RecyclerView`.

Now See [Artifact mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings).. Use same latest versions for all androidx libraries.

Check out [Class mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).

1. `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`  =====> `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`
2. `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` ======> `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's the problem really thank you!